# What is considered a suitable notice period for a software developer?

Tags: contract

I'm being asked by the company I work for to extend my notice period. I'm not outright against it (in fact it's somewhat flattering in a way) but it has made me wonder what a typical notice period might be for a C# software developer?

Comment: What are they trading for this?

Comment: Well nothing directly. I have been very fortunate to receive a payrise recently, but discussions about that didn't include the extension to my notice period (and in fact the extension was asked of me some time ago, but I never signed and returned the agreement). Again, I'm not concerned about it particularly, but wondered what others in a similar position to me have. It just seems like the jump from one month to three months is quite a big one all in one go.

Comment: it's huge, definitely not worth the hassle unless you're getting something good in return.

Comment: To prevent this from being too localized, make it relative to what is normally acceptable for all jobs.

Answer (score 2):

I think 1 month is typical, for more senior people (not just software developers) 3 months is not unusual. I've never seen anything longer than that except for director level, where it could be 6 to 12 months.

Comment: +1 Its sad that the companies that demand 3 months notice are the same ones that push for a 2 weeks or less notice for new hires.Its like WTF?

Comment: @AIG that's why we have laws here that require companies to give notice at least twice as long in advance as they require from employees. So if they want a 3 month notice period from me, they have to give me at least 6 months notice when terminating me (firing because of things like fraud excluded of course).

Comment: @jwenting nice laws.I was referring to the huge difference between hiring policy verses notice periods.

Answer (score 2):

2 weeks is bare-minimum in the US (you may want your question to be less localized and made relative to what is considered standard) for most jobs. I'm relocating, but want to work remotely for my current company. They've asked for 3 months notice if I leave within the next 9 months. I couldn't sign that fast enough. There are no penalties stipulated.

Answer (score 1):

A month is the standard notice period for *most* jobs in the UK.

Have you handed in your notice, or are they realising your value to them?

I'd be looking for something back from them if you haven't even handed in your notice yet.

Comment: I've not even been considering handing in my notice, tbh. I had a letter some time ago that I totally forgot to reply to and have today received a reminder. My title is "Software Developer" but I do get involved in lots more than just writing code, so I guess I'm fairly valuable. It just seems like the jump from one month to three months is quite a big one all in one go.

Comment: Strange one. And they haven't given any reason? Are they demanding it? (eg what will happen if you do not agree?). You don't want to come across as an arse, but neither do you want to bend over and let them force a new "condition" in your contract.

Comment: I think the original letter (which I've now lost) was justifying it as my being valuable. Of course the flipside is that I can expect 3 months notice if I was made redundant, so it does work both ways. I imagine there's more chance of me leaving one day than the company going under, so the risk really is still mine.

Answer (score 1):

As an employer I see it differently. If the employee is integral to the core product, no matter their job title, and if it is difficult to recruit replacements (perhaps due to location) and if the company feels there has been a historical lack or insufficient documentation then 3 months would be standard and appropriate length of notice.

It protects the employee to give time to find another job if the company gets into difficulties and it protects the company to give it confidence to offer good development programmes and investment is staff and working environment.

It should be remembered employment should be a two way relationship. And many many more people leave their employ by their own decision than the companies decision.

The company has to think of what is left after you leave and the protection of all the other employees you leave behind. It's not a service.

Comment: if the company wants the employee to accept a very long notice period, the company should extend the employee the same courtesy and give them even more notice. Sadly that usually doesn't happen. Company expects undying loyalty from their staff but wants to be able to get rid of them at a moment's notice.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK you'll sometimes see something like 2 weeks, plus 1 week per year worked over 2 years, up to 12 weeks. So the longer you've worked there, the longer the notice period.

As pointed out by Mumbles in the comments below, this is the legal default as given on [Directgov](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Employment/RedundancyAndLeavingYourJob/Resigningorretiring/DG_175837).

However, 1 month is fairly typical, as others have stated.

Comment: That's more generally the notice they're required to give to you if they want you gone.

Comment: I was about to say this, as this is the legal default as given by http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Employment/RedundancyAndLeavingYourJob/Resigningorretiring/DG_175837

Comment: Good link Mumbles, I'll update the answer to include it!

Answer (score 0):

One month is the typical notice period. Note that it's also the period the next employer expects you to join after. So, if you agreed to extend your notice period to be more than the typical in the market in your country, it may cause you a problem if you decided to move. Either you will be rejected because you will take too long to join or you will have to make a deal of some kind with the original employer to be able to leave.

My advice is to stick to the typical.